# Subversion is ignoring files which haven't been set to be ignored

Tags: linux, svn, version-control

I have a subversion repository in which when I create a file with a `.a` extension, the file is not listed by `svn status` and shows up as ignored (`I`) when I run a `svn status --no-ignore`.

The problem is though, I have not set any ignores on any folders in the repository, when I run `svn propget svn:global-ignores .` at the top level it says the property is not set, and my `~/.subversion/config` file has the default line for global ignores commented out (and I have never changes this file):

```
[miscellany]
### Set global-ignores to a set of whitespace-delimited globs
### which Subversion will ignore in its 'status' output, and
### while importing or adding files and directories.
### '*' matches leading dots, e.g. '*.rej' matches '.foo.rej'.
# global-ignores = *.o *.lo *.la *.al .libs *.so *.so.[0-9]* *.a *.pyc *.pyo __pycache__
#   *.rej *~ #*# .#* .*.swp .DS_Store [Tt]humbs.db
```

What else could be causing files with a `.a` extension from being ignored?

Comment: What's your OS?

Comment: @bahrep I'm on Zorin OS 16.2

Answer (score 0):

Besides `svn:ignore`, `svn:global-ignores` and the `[miscellany]` section of the `/.subversion/config` file, the [ignores can be configured in Windows Registry](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.confarea.html#svn.advanced.confarea.windows-registry). It makes sense to check registry if you are on Windows.